# Переменные окружения для nmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile

Пытаюсь использовать nmake для сборки [этого проекта](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/download), но получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> export.c .\export.c(20) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory

Я так понимаю, нужно в какой-то переменной записать путь к заголовочным файлам (на машине стоит vs2013). Как правильно это сделать? И есть ли еще подводные камни, на которые можно наткнуться, вызывая nmake?

Comment: Вы его используете в командной строке, ярлык для которой создается при инсталляции VS? Там вроде бы все необходимые переменные настроены. Или просто в окне командной строки, не имеющем отношения к VS?

Comment: В командной строке, открытой из директории, где лежит makefile. Если запускаю vs command promt и скармливаю ему полный путь к файлу сборки - то он просто напросто не видит переходы из этого make-файла. Кст., может их там абсолютными путями прописать ?))

Comment: Не знаю, тут надо смотреть как минимум в вашей командной строке, из которой работаете, результаты команды set...

Comment: не находит файлы, вероятно, всё же компилятор. без сообщения об ошибке и [краткого завершённого примера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ответить на вопрос вряд ли возможно. кстати, makefile написан вручную (скопирован откуда-то) или генерировался какой-то программой?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, конкретнее - собирал PyQt5, для того, чтобы его собрать нужно сначала собрать sip [http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/download]. Вот последнюю тулзу я и не смог собрать.

Comment: ни *ms/windows*, ни *ms/nmake* у меня нет, поэтому конкретики подсказать не могу. скачал архив по вашей ссылке, выполнил `python configure.py`, который **сгенерировал** *makefile*. после запуска *make* (версия от проекта *gnu*) получил ошибку от *gnu/gcc*, что не найден *Python.h*. тут понятно: всего лишь надо установить заголовочные файлы python-а. в моём дистрибутиве это пакет *python-dev*. вам же надо проделать что-то аналогичное. цель: установить в систему и сделать досутпными для компилятора заголовочные файлы python-а.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin:

.\extracts.c(20) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
export.c
.\export.c(20) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory

Вышесказанные Вами действия я проделал, с ними проблем не было. Вот примеры ошибок, которые выдает мне на выходе nmake.

Comment: Таким образом, насколько я правильно понимаю суть проблемы, мне нужно указать путь к стандартным заголовочным файлам VS, причем инициализировать этим путем некоторую переменную, которую скушает nmake и будет знать, откуда их брать.

Answer (score 1):

**в результате дискуссии в комментариях**:

как именно должна называться переменная и что именно она должна содержать, целиком и полностью зависит от используемого вами компилятора. возможно, определиться помогут результаты поиска приведённой вами ошибки:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h'

например, ответы на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7206393/4827341).

вставить же переменную в *makefile* не сложно. где-нибудь в начале файла добавьте строку:

```
переменная=значение
```

если `значение` содержит пробелы, вероятно, стоит заключить его в кавычки:

```
переменная="значение с пробелами"
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.